# Paypal Subscription button error

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

This is my markup

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="shubhangi254@gmail.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="XYZ"/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest"/>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>
</form>
```

With this it redirects to paypal, but when I login with sandbox test account email it gives following error:
`The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again.`

Any idea?

Comment: the email in business field you are using is of sandbox's or real? Because for testing purposes it shuld be sandbox;s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shubhangi254@gmail.com is not a Sandbox account. It's a developer account used for accessing https://developer.paypal.com/
You must also create a test buyer/seller account via https://developer.paypal.com/ > Test Accounts.
The value of 'business' will be the 'email address' of the Seller test account.